# how to solve onTouchListener android

Tags: android, imageview, ontouchlistener

i have problem, I am successfully to display image in alert dialog custom, but when I want to add event `onTouchListener` to the image, i cannot get problem : `the method setonTouchListener in Type View is not applicable`. Here my source code :

```
public class ViewDetailItem extends Activity implements OnTouchListener{
   bla bla...
   onloaditem()
}
```

here onloaditem() sourcecode :

```
 imgmain.setImageResource(imgID);
        imgmain.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {          
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                /*Intent MyIntentDetailItem=new Intent(getBaseContext(), ViewDetailItemFullscreen.class);
                Other_class.setItemCode(timgName);
                startActivity(MyIntentDetailItem);*/

                LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(ViewDetailItem.this);
                final View inputdialogcustom = li.inflate(R.layout.activity_view_detail_item_fullscreen2, null);                
                final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(ViewDetailItem.this); 


                final ImageView imgmainbig=((ImageView) inputdialogcustom.findViewById(R.id.imgmainbig));
                imgID=getBaseContext().getResources().getIdentifier(imgName2+"_1", "drawable", getBaseContext().getPackageName());  
                imgmainbig.setImageResource(imgID);
imgmainbig.setOnTouchListener(this);

}
}
```

The problem refers to `imgmainbig.setOnTouchListener(this);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
imgmainbig.setOnTouchListener(this);
```

to

```
imgmainbig.setOnTouchListener(ViewDetailItem.this);
```

cause `this` refers to annonymous inner class that implements `OnClickListener` interface.

Since your Activity class implements interface  `OnTouchListener` use `ViewDetailItem.this`